# Usage of comparator in java

Tags: java, comparator

Comparator is a interface in java then how is it that it allows new Comparator() and overrides compare method? 
Are there any other classes/interfaces also like that?
Please help its very confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do `Comparator x = new Comparator();`

What you can do is

```
   Comparator x = new Comparator(){ 
       // some implementation code here
   };
```

That is something else (it includes the definition of an anonymous subclass of Comparator).
It is more or less just a shorthand for declaring a new class that implements Comparator and making an instance of it and the same time.

And, yes, you can do that with all interfaces or non-final classes (don't need to be abstract).